# how to delete comments while parsing text C++

Tags: c++, ifstream, text-parsing, ppm

I'm trying to parse text in C++ using "ifstream" from a .ppm file but I want to avoid comments in the file which start with character "#" and finish at the end of the line..I can track the comment character with the code below...Anyone can help on how to dismiss the rest of the words until character '\n'?

```
string word;            
file>>word;
if(strcmp(word, "#")){
   //TO DO...Dismiss all characters till the end of the line
}
```

Comment: Probably it's better to use `std::getline()` as a primary source of input for your case. Non comment lines can be inspected further with `std::istringstream` then.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::getline()` & `continue` the `while` loop if `line[0] == '#'`:

```
std::ifstream file( "foo.txt" );
std::string line;
while( std::getline( file, line ) )
{
    if( line.empty() )
        continue;

    if( '#' == line[0] )
        continue;

    std::istringstream liness( line );
    // pull words out of liness...
}
```

Or if the `#` can occur mid-line you can just ignore everything after it:

```
std::ifstream file( "foo.txt" );
std::string line;
while( std::getline( file, line ) )
{
    std::istringstream liness( line.substr( 0, line.find_first_of( '#' ) ) );
    // pull words out of liness...
}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that '#' will always be at 0th location?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the comments you want to strip, you might consider using regular expressions:

[Removing hash comments that are not inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791143/removing-hash-comments-that-are-not-inside-quotes)

For example, which of these would be considered comments:

```
# Start of line comment
Stuff here # mid-line comment
Contact "Tel# 911"
```

Would you want to strip all three of the above examples after the `#`?

Or are you only considering it a comment if the very first character of the line is a `#`?

Comment: I'm considering both situations

Comment: You could use a regular expression such as `(?:"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|[^"#])*(#|$)` to capture the comment